# JMeter zip file download from application

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I have a requirement to select multiple files in my application and need to download the zip files after processsing. Using Jmeter I am unable to download the file , getting the error message:

> {"exception_body":{"http_response_code":400,"message":"The request could not be understood due to malformed syntax.","debug_message":"HTTP 400 Bad Request","error_code":1000}}

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: according to error you didn't format request correctly

Comment: I pass the my header request correctly, still facing the issue..any suggestions/help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you error screenshot:-

1-The request is not formatted correctly. Need to correct this. Once done, it will show status 200 but will not download anything. Considering this is the request to download the zip.

2. In order to download the zip, use "[Save Response to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file)" listener under the download request. This will download the zip file.

Update for regular expression, check below:-
[image]

Comment: How to pass the correct request, I have passed all the request headers correctly. Any help

Comment: I can only give some pointer. 1. Record the request using fiddler or any other tool and check the request header and parameters. 2. Check that dynamic values are properly correlated. For this record 2 times and compare the request sent.

Comment: Yes, I did same thing, Record the script with Loadrunner & Fiddler and compare the request. same request headers passed in JMeter.

Comment: How can i capture the Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryxqI35B5QBnU9clDB
The boundary every time changing.

Comment: It seems like you upload/download request is having this. Use multi-part checkbox and provide the file upload pre-requisites like filepath,parameter,mime type. Use recorder to get this info. Check this for more help:-https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter

Comment: I used this option also, but no luck

Comment: You can try Postman as suggested by Facundo. If that is successful then check what is the request it is sending using fiddler or any sniffer tool.

Comment: Now It's working static value, but each download dynamically id generating , I captured the dynamic value. During replay time dynamic value passing append with %20. because of this issue. getting below error.
{"exception_body":{"http_response_code":500,"message":"Improper job id passed to update is downloaded flag : 99128 ","debug_message":"Improper job id passed to update is downloaded flag : 99128 ","error_code":1000}}

https:/{url}/otmmapi/v4/jobs/99128%20

Comment: %20 is space..remove it while passing the dynamic value.

Comment: how can i ignore the space, any function can i use.

Comment: While capturing the dynamic value, check it should only capture value without space. I am assuming you are using some extractor to get the value. Show your extractor snapshot and value that needs to be captured. Second, get the value using JSR223 postprocessor and use groovy trim() function and then fetch the trimmed value. Ref:-http://grails.asia/groovy-trim-examples

Comment: This response getting ""job_id":99255,"unexportable_count":" capturing : 99255 value using below Reg expression: job_id\":(.*),

Comment: Use ""job_id":(.+?)," or ""job_id":(.+?), as regular expression. Check the snapshot. Hope this help.

Comment: still the request append opentext.com/otmmapi/v4/jobs/99256%20. Not sure why the space append in the request

Comment: Only thing I can point is to check the HTTP sampler/request where you are inserting the variable. Specially, check for the space after the variable in the HTTP request path..i.e. at the end.

Comment: Now working used this: ${__javaScript('${Param}'.trim())} file successfully downloaded

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with JMeter and solved it used Postman to send the request. You can save the response using "Send and Download". This will download the zipfile.