# Trying to download zip file using Jmeter

Tags: methods, download, get, jmeter, zip

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5Nnh.png)Trying to run get method which download the zip file.
For this have Get HTTP Request also applied listener as a Save Response to a file where i gave the path to download zip file.
After executing the script Download path have file with the response content only not actual zip file.

enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs0Y7.png)
In this i am trying get method to download zip

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtiDw.png)
In this when the file is saved on given location have same reponse in file not a zip file. (Response printed is zip file name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JMeter zip file download from application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51213747/jmeter-zip-file-download-from-application)

Comment: @Amol nope its kind of different

Answer (score 0):

Change the position of "Save Response to a file" under the download request. Currently, it is under thread group.

[image]
Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried the scenario as you mentioned but its just downloading normal file with Download Job Response Body (Name of zip file only).
But no luck :(

Comment: Please show your save response file configuration snapshot also.

Comment: Check save successful result only checkbox. From jmeter doc."If selected, then only successful responses are saved"..Hope this solve the problem but if not, please share if there is any error in jmeter console/log.

Comment: this time file downloaded with name as "1.octet-stream" data contains same as previous one Response Body.
And the request work successfully Status Code 200 OK so there are no error in jmeter console/log

In Header manager i am using Content Type as below "application/octet-stream;text/plain "

Comment: If it is zip file then try content type as "application/zip"

Comment: applied content type as a application/zip but same file downloading.

Comment: Check by recording jmeter/blazemeter plugin that content/header are same. Manually, if you download it provides zip...if yes..i think some value in request or header is different..Also, check if you rename the file to .zip and validate the content.

Comment: Yes i have recorded with Blazemeter and using same header which is in the recorder script.

Comment: I am out of ideas :)..In url download request path field, there is jobids and format...Are these dynamic parameters. Also, check the relevance of format in the URL path..Image REF (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs0Y7.png)

Comment: Jobs id and format are static field these are not dynamic.
have tried giving jobs id and format through URL and as a Body data.
Still no luck :(
The only thing is downloading a file with type octet stream with response content (name of zip file)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below settings and it works fine for me. Also, I have found that there are some differences in "Save Responses to a file" element when compared with mine. This might exists because I am using some old version of Jmeter. Fields like "Filename Prefix" does not have a text field to enter the file name.

[image]